# How can I show my own Toast in the foreground of a Dialog?

Tags: java, android, dialog, toast, foreground

I start my own Toast by using this code:

```
TextView txtViewToast = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtViewToast); txtViewToast.setText(R.string.free_slots); Toast();
```

This code works fine. It shows me the Toast, but in the background. I want to show this code in the foreground, over the Dialog.

```
final Dialog dialogPopupGewonnen = new Dialog(Start.this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen);
    dialogPopupGewonnen.setContentView(R.layout.popupgewonnen);
dialogPopupGewonnen.show();
```

Comment: Thank you!!! ;-)

Comment: I converted my comment to an answer, so that you can accept it and remove the post from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the Toast in the Dialog itself, so that it goes in front of it, instead of being covered by it